# Take the closest sibling data using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the table having class as **select_fly** for td, i want complete html of td with class select_fly.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td width="5%"><input type="radio" name="onward" class="onward" value="1" checked></td>
<td class="select_fly">
<div class="disp_trip">
hai
</div> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Below is the script which i wrote for taking the html data. But do no wats wrong in this code its showing undefined. Please help me out with this !!!!

```
var owner = $('input[name=onward]:checked').closest('td').siblings('td.select_fly').html();
```

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ryzhrgx3/

Comment: you can use `$('input[name=onward]:checked').closest('td').next().html();`

Comment: It works for me too. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jENgJG

Comment: Are you sure you are including the jquery library in the code? What browser are you using?

Comment: i am using the chrome @kunl , this link is working for me codepen.io/anon/pen/jENgJG. including jquery library means which one u are talking abt? i have included script also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you are placing your script in the wrong place in code. Put it after the table tag, it worked for me in this way.

Comment: yes u r telling right actually after loading td it should load the script, its working thanks for your support guys !!!!